Australian Albers raster and WGS84 vector will not register
With QGIS 3.40 and MacOS 15.1, I cannot get the Australian Albers raster and a CSV text CSV file to line up correctly.
The raster is Australian Albers. I cannot tell if it is GDA94 or GDA2020 but with a difference of 1.5m between the two this should not be critical. I have / Add raster / and confirmed it displays projected as EPSG9473. The extent is Australia Onshore (as distinct from other versions that include nearby offshore islands or the larger extent to include distant Australian islands).
My CSV file has lat - lon in decimal degrees. I have used Layer / Add Layer / Add delimited text ... / and successfully added the points as a WGS84 layer.  I have used a shape file version of the same data and other shape files all as WGS84 decimal degrees. Their CRS is set as EPSG:4326 - WGS84.
In multiple combinations, in every case, the two layers (raster Aus Albers) and vector (points or lines WGS84) display with the raster as a tiny patch (<1mm square) and,  displaced, with the vector occupying half the screen.

Zooming in to each layer has both displaying correctly.
When I use ArcGIS Pro with the same files and do the equivalent processing, the raster and the vector layers are correctly registered.
The raster is
https://fed.dcceew.gov.au/maps/cde3109f9105411c88901e69e7f0ccbe/about?_gl=1*1yvz410*_ga*MTk0OTIxNzY3NS4xNjgwNTA2ODEw*_ga_1M2TBC9WWS*MTY5MzQ2Mzk3NC4xOS4xLjE2OTM0NjQ0MzIuMC4wLjA .
Everything @user2856 said fits my understanding of how things in a GIS work. I confirm I get the expected results in ArcGIS Pro but I cannot make things work in QGIS in MacOS 3.40 nor in a Windows 11 emulatation with QGIS 3.34. I try here to document my steps in MacOS 3.40 with screenshots in the hope my mistake becomes obvious.
Open QGIS, New project, set CRS to EPSG 3577  Aus Albers GDA94 at lower right.
Select menue Layer / Add Layer / Add raster / In Data Source Manager | rater browse Source to select "myraster.ovr" Add.
In window "Specify CRS for layer aus6_Op_mvs with Predefined CRS, Filter field is empty, with Recently Used Coordinate Reference Systems, select "EPSG:3577",  click OK.
Map displays, see screenshot, looks correct, coordinates (with cursor in lower right are numbers not degrees, CRS is right.

Add a csv file with point lat - lon decimal degree coordinates near Melbourne (lower right); select Layer / Add Layer / Add delimited text layer / in Data Source Manager window / in File name field browse to file TestData.csv, File Format has CVS set, Record and Fields Options accept defaults, Geometry Definition has Point coordinates selected with X Field and Y field  as Longitude and Latitude respectively, Geometry CRS is EPSG:4326 - WGS84 which is the intended CRS, Layer Settings Sample Data is correct, see screenshot, click Add.

New window displays Select Transformation for Test Data, option 3 selected because this matches the area of the raster in use , click OK.
Select the two layers, Zoom to layer(s), see screenshot.

Yet again the same failure to align the two layers.
Why is that?
Adding the files in my source raster
aus6_0p_mvs.aux.xml
aus6_0p_mvs.ovr
aus6_0p_mvs.ovr.aux.xml
info
mvs6_0p_by_name.lyr
mvs6_0p_by_name.lyr.xml
mvs6_0p_by_number.lyr
mvs6_0p_by_number.lyr.xml
Readme_instructions_Pre1750.txt
What is the correct way to add the raster? The .ovr file is the only file I can add to the QGIS project; ignoring the xml files.

I can't reproduce, CSV with WGS84 (EPSG:4326) lon = X and lat = Y displays correctly over the NVIS raster. I didn't try GDA2020 Albers as the NVIS raster is GDA94 Albers (EPSG:3577).

Can you edit your question to include a sample lon, lat coordinate?

Many thanks. The raster includes all of onshore Australia,

Please tell me where should I have seen that the raster NVIS is GDA94.

Some details on the addition of the CSV / vector layer./Users/davidnicholls/Desktop/Screenshot 2024-12-10 at 16.39.21.png

I tried to include a screen shot.

You can't add screenshots to comments. If you edit your question, you can add screenshots to the question body.  The Edit link is right under the question on the left. Can you provide a sample csv record including header (what I should have saidinstead of lon, lat coordinate). If you right click on the raster layer name in the qgis layers panel , select Properties... then the Information tab you will see the raster coordinate system (may need to scroll down)

I can reproduce if I add a delimited text CSV layer with coordinates in EPSG:3577 but (incorrectly) tell QGIS that they are EPSG:4326. Please ensure your lat, lon
coordinates look something like -NN.NN,NNN.NN e.g. -29.86,147.75.  If they look like 1861863,-3313876 then they are def. not lat, lon.

The provided URL doesn't allow to download the raster layer.

Why are you using the ".ovr" file? Looking at the second screenshot provided, it is clear that you have not imported the actual raster layer: it would be impossible to display the whole Australia in the map window at a scale of 1:80000.

Thank you Andrea.  The reason the URL no longer works, is that version 6 has been replaced with v 7. Version 7 is a file geodatabase and so is not directly accessible to GIS, I believe.
On your second point, from my perspective, you only emphasise my puzzlement on how QGIS is handling the files. I believe you are wrong in as much as, if I zoom individually to each layer, one at a time, it is clear to me that the full datasets are included in the project. Screenshots demonstrate, pls see above.
v 6 and 7 can be added to the same QGIS project with north-road  SLYR.

@DavidNicholls, an ESRI file geodatabase can be directly accessible to QGIS. An .ovr file only contains "overviews" of the actual rastar image, not the actual georeferrenced raster image. In fact, from the screenshot it looks like not georeferenced. Why don't you add the corresponding .tiff file which contain the actual raster image?
May you please provide the extent, the CRS, the resolution, the number of pixels of the raster layer? May you please provide all the the raster layer's file?

Andrea - many thanks for helping. Before answering your questions, I provide the directory listing of my raster source. There is no .tiff. The ovr is the only file I can get into QGIS, in the original posting.

My source raster is available in a dropbox - the link
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/8zfi7sej8dsbm54rab8qi/AJFpbY1yjgjYjFjugIhpObw?rlkey=r7ngjzegxqcjgk4wqjy53mmmt&dl=0

@DavidNicholls have you manaed to correctly add the layer as explained in my answer?

Andrea,   I am so sorry.  I did respond thanking you. To my distress, I now see that edit failed to save. Yes, Add Raster/ set source to the /aus6_0p_mvs/hrd.adf worked as instructed. The only way I could add the lyr files, was to use the add-in SLYR which gave me versions of the complex legend.

So, remember to "accept" the answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

The raster layer available at https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/8zfi7sej8dsbm54rab8qi/AJFpbY1yjgjYjFjugIhpObw?rlkey=r7ngjzegxqcjgk4wqjy53mmmt&dl=0 is an Arc/Info Binary Grid raster layer.
In order to correctly import and display it with the correct georeferenceing information using QGIS, you need to go to the Data Source Manager -> Raster dialog window and set the source raster dataset to the hdr.adf file contained in the aus6_0p_mvs folder and then add the layer.
The CRS of such raster layer will be automatically and correctly recognised as EPSG:3577 "GDA94 / Australian Albers" (which is consistent with the info contained in the prj.adf file: "Projection ALBERS, Datum GDA94, Spheroid GRS80").
Such raster layer has a dimension in pixels of 40090 x 38360 and the extent of -1887000,-4840000 : 2122000,-1004000.

Side note: the .ovr file only contains a low resolution (20045 x 19180) "overview" bitmap (see: OVR pyramid files) of the raster layer and doesn't contain the correct georeferencing information (extent 0,-19180 : 20045,0 / crs Unknown).

Thank you @Andrea. I implemented your advice and I satisfied the data is correctly incorprated into QGIS. David

more of a comment with screenshot:
Ran this through FME and exported to GeoTiff
It shows a different projection.
EPGS 7845 GDA2020/GA LCC


Note:FME can read the dataset and assign the CRS from the file which was COG (Cloud-Optimized GeoTIFF) Reader/Writer

The .ovr file doesn't contain the actual raster layer's data. It only contain a low resolution "overview" bitmap of the raster layer and doesn't contain the correct georeferencing information.

Thank you, Mapperz
The original data source did specify Australian Albers GDA94. These data have been replaced with version 7.
